# How to move some files under version control from one project to another in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mercurial, projects-and-solutions

I use c++, mercurial as VCS and IDE - Visual Studio 2015. Sometimes I need to extract some files from project to separate project (in the same solution). Now for that I have to:

1. create new project in the same solution
2. use mercurial "rename" for all files I need to move
3. remove files from source project manually via Visual Studio
4. add files to destination project manually via Visual Studio
5. fix includes in these files
6. maybe something else (change namespace, etc.)

It would be nice making items 2, 3 and 4 at once (and somehow automatically). I Can't find anything suitable so I will be very grateful for any advice about it (maybe some tools, scripts, Visual Studio extensions or something else).

Comment: You could do step #2 after step #4, using either `hg move --after` or `hg addremove -s`. Either of these could slightly simplify the process you have to follow.

Comment: Also just FYI the project files could be manually edited - they are just text files. This also might be quicker than using the IDE's GUI to modify the project file contents.

Comment: You can try https://bitbucket.org/zzsergant/hgsccpackage/wiki/Home. I've been using it with VS for more than a year now when I started developing on Windows.